# Yii2 display model name in URL

Tags: url, yii2

Now my view url is looking like this `example.com/item/view?id=1`, i need it too look like this: `example.com/item/item-name`. As I understood, I need to use SluggableBehavior. But how do I configure my URLManager rules and SluggableBehavior to access this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure rules in `UrlManager`:

```
[
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            // ...
            'rules' => [
                'item/<slug:[\w\-]+>' => 'item/view',
                // ...
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Then you create URL like this:

```
Url::to(['item/view', 'slug' => $model->slug]);
```

And in action:

```
public function actionView($slug) {
    $model = Item::findOne(['slug' => $slug]);
    // rest of action logic
}
```

It is worth to take look at  [handling pretty URLs documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#using-pretty-urls).

Configuring `SluggableBehavior` is [quite well documented](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior):

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'title',
            // 'slugAttribute' => 'slug',
        ],
    ];
}
```